# How to create periodic network request with RxJava only in foreground?

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java2, android-livedata

How should approach such problem: Suppose I need to create periodic network requests, which should only occur while app is in the foreground, because if they occur in the background network **requests can terminate**, with background service. I know that you would need this code for periodic requests:

```
  Observable.fromCallable(networkRequest())
          .repeatWhen(observable -> observable.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

The problem is that, it will continue to be executed when app is in background..

I thought about adding **LiveData somehow** in order to **unsubscribe from this in onStop and continue in onStart**. However, I can't find a correct approach to that.

If I would add all this to **CompositeDisposable**, it could **terminate my network requests**, if I would call disposable.clear() in onStop. So this is not correct solution, too.

i would also like to get solution for ViewModel, but if that is not possible to do in it, then activity would also suit as an observer.

Comment: LiveData is already life cycle aware component. It's best approach for you

Comment: Yes, but how should I combine response from RxJava and adding livedata on top of that? What I would need is like: observeOnLifecycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **LifecycleObserver** like this

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
Observable.defer(this::getNetworkObservable)
      .repeatWhen(observable -> observable.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
private void onAppBackgrounded() {
    isOnline=false;
}


@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
private void onAppForegrounded() {
   // restart working
isOnline=true;
}


private networkRequest() getNetworkObservable(){
    if(isOnline){
      return networkRequest();  
    }else {
        return Observable.empty();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: I have such owner in application, I don't know how should I pause  my RxJava observable chain correctly in onAppBackground and start in onAppForeground

Comment: check this link for subscribe and unsubscribe observable.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209707/how-to-subscribe-and-unsubscribe-or-cancel-an-rxjava-observable

Comment: Yes I know this, the problem actually different. composite disposable terminates network request. I don't need that.

Comment: check edited answer. it will not terminate your call.

Comment: but it will not make call also if  try to repeate call and app is background.

Comment: your improved solution is almost what I need! Thanks, however how can I include Observable.fromCallable in the chain in order to not repeat network requests?

Comment: you have to dispose Observable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196243/discussion-between-kuldip-patel-and-viktor-vostrikov).